# Countdown from PHP date format

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i develop a countdown in Javascript / jQuery which works with PHP's datetime (Has to countdown real-time without refreshing)?

So when the date is example: 2013-06-2 it countdown days, hours and minutes that is back till the date.

It has to works in following format:

```
<li><small>@@days@@</small><span>Days</span></li>
<li><small>@@hours@@</small><span>Hours</span></li>
<li><small>@@minutes@@</small><span>Minutes</span></li>
```

Or should i edit the datetime to timestamp?!

Comment: What date is `2013-06-02`? it means different dates in different parts of the world.

Answer (score 2):

First see this live demo - http://jsfiddle.net/im4aLL/yjdZf/1/

Used jQuery for demo -

```
function countdown(){
    today = new Date();
    BigDay = new Date("2013-06-2");
    msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ;
    timeLeft = (BigDay.getTime() - today.getTime());
    e_daysLeft = timeLeft / msPerDay;
    daysLeft = Math.floor(e_daysLeft);
    e_hrsLeft = (e_daysLeft - daysLeft)*24;
    hrsLeft = Math.floor(e_hrsLeft);
    minsLeft = Math.floor((e_hrsLeft - hrsLeft)*60);
    $('#countdown').html("<ul><li><small>" + daysLeft + "</small><span>Days</span></li><li><small>" + hrsLeft +"</small><span>Hours</span></li><li><small>" + minsLeft + "</small><span>Minutes</span></li></ul>");
}

setInterval(countdown, 1000);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Now, change in countdown function

```
BigDay = new Date("2013-06-2");
```

to

```
BigDay = new Date($your_date);
```

I hope this will help you.

#### update

if you need second countdown also then see this - http://jsfiddle.net/im4aLL/yjdZf/2/

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work properly in Firefox. Check http://pointsafari.dk - works fine in Chrome, but not Firefox. Says "NaN" and "NaN"... <script>setInterval("countdown(\''.$row['slutter'].' 00:00:00\',\'c'.$w.'\')", 1000);</script>

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to initialize the countdown with the server timestamp with PHP and start counting down with Javascript.

In fact you won't be able to implement a countdown with PHP since it is not client-side.